# Delete row on website using Node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm working with Node JS, building an app for a school project, where pictures has to been uploaded, edited and deleted by a Mysql database. I've managed the upload page, pictures can be edit, but I just can't succeed with the DELETE query. On my webpage the user has to press the delete button to delete the picture row with data like driver, team, etc. This is my code:

INDEX.EJS

```
<% if(pictures.length){ %>     
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Driver</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                    <th>Location</th>                       
                    <% if(admin) { %>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    <% } %>
                </tr>
    <% } %>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/<%= pictures[i].image %>" /></td>
                <td><%= pictures[i].driver %></td>
                <td><%= pictures[i].team %></td>
                <td><%= pictures[i].location %></td>                    
                <% if(admin) { %>
                <td><a href="/edit/<%= pictures[i].id %>" >Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="/edit/delete/<%= pictures[i].id %>">Delete</a></td>
                <% } %>

    <% } %>
            </tr>                   
            </table>    

</div>
```

EDIT.JS

```
router.get('/delete/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query("DELETE FROM pictures WHERE id = ? ", [id], function(err, results) {
         res.redirect('/');
         console.log('Some data has been deleted')
    });
  });
});
```

APP.JS

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'), // Anders kan er geen POST worden gebruikt, de POST zit in de body
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    myConnection = require('express-myconnection');

// Set up de database
var dbOptions = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'fcdeen_user',
    password: 'wEvGT9ctm8KUxdTD',
    database: 'fcdeen'
};

// Definieer de routers
var indexRoutes = require('./routes/index'),    
    loginRoutes = require('./routes/login'),
    uploadRoutes = require('./routes/upload'),
    editRoutes = require('./routes/edit');

// Applicatie wordt aangemaakt
var app = express();

// Gebruik de session
app.use(session({
  secret: "Its_A_veRy_DarK_SecreT",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Voeg de bodyparser middleware aan de app toe, handelt de POST requests af
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Voeg connectie middleware toe aan app
app.use(myConnection(mysql, dbOptions, 'single'));

// Set de view engine op EJS
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Hierdoor weet express welke static file er gebruikt moet worden
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Verbind de Routers met de routes
app.use('/', indexRoutes);
app.use('/login', loginRoutes);
app.use('/upload', uploadRoutes);
app.use('/edit', editRoutes);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

// Start de server, App luistert naar poort 8080
app.listen(8080);
console.log('Launch at port 8080');
```

When i press the delete button, I get this error:

Cannot GET /10  (10 is the ID of the row I want to delete)

Comment: It sounds like the picture is deleted on the database and then you try to re-render the route with a picture of ID 10.   Can you confirm the record with ID 10 is deleted from the database once your code runs

Comment: No, ID 10 still remains in the database. Also when i run the code it doesnt return anything to the terminal